# How to pass local scope of nested ng-repeat element with ng-blur?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-strap

I have three nested `ng-repeat`elements. I would like to access the scope of the elements in the innermost nested `ng-repeat` with a function called by `ng-blur`.

I know I can access the scope of the innermost nested element with a listener on the AngularStrap typeahead. It's the `$scope` property of the fourth parameter, `elem`, in the listener shown in this forum: https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/81.

How can I pass this `elem` object to my controller with `ng-blur`?

Comment: Have you attempted with any code yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the case of the following `ng-repeats`:

```
<div ng-repeat="continent in continents">
    <div ng-repeat="country in continent.countries">
        <div ng-repeat="city in country.cities">
            <input type="text" ng-blur="myFunction()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can access the scope of the most nested `city` `<div>` in your controller like so:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(){
    console.log(this.city);
    console.log(this.city.someVariable);
}
```